# class attribute using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble with class attributes using Beautiful Soup.

My code is :

```
ls = ([x.get_text().strip('\n') for x in bs.find_all("div",{"class":"other-info","class":"description","class":"n-title search-detail"})])
```

But I get only description class not other class information. How can I get other class information  in same code.

Comment: can you post the url if not sensitive

Comment: Why don't you go for `.select()` instead of `.find_all()`? Selector are very easy to control when it comes to deal with complex structure of `DOM`. That would definitely be tidier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can use `strip=True` with the [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) function to strip all the whitespace from the text. Secondly, a dictionary can't have duplicate keys. The `find_all()` function accepts a `list` as a value for an attribute. Also, those brackets `()` around the list are redundant. Remove them.

Use this:

```
ls = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in bs.find_all("div", {"class": ["other-info", "description", "n-title search-detail"]})]
```